# compare consecutive values of an array numpy

Tags: arrays, numpy

I have a vector A and I want to find all the "i" values of the array which are bigger than the neighboring values, i.e. right before (i-1) and right after (i+1). I wrote a simple code (surely with mistakes) that should print the array (y_maxtab) containing the "i" values. I try to run and It gets stacked. Could you help me on that?

```
import numpy as np

y_maxtab = []


A=np.array([2.0,2.5,1.7,5,7,8,9,3,5,3,7,8])

i=1

while i <= len(A):
   if A[i] > A[i-1] and a[i] > A[i+1]:
         y_maxtab.append(A[i])
         i=i+1
print y_maxtab
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, your code as is has some problems.

1. If the first `if` statement fails, you will never increment `i`, and will be stuck in an infinite loop.
2. The second clause of the `if` statement has an undefined reference (`a`).
3. The `while` statement will allow values of `i` which will cause `IndexError`s with `A[i]` and `A[i+1]`.

If you are committed to keeping the code in the same form, you could change it so that it looks like

```
i = 1
while i < len(A)-1:
    if A[i] > A[i-1] and a[i] > A[i+1]:
        y_maxtab.append(A[i])
    i=i+1
print y_maxtab
# [2.5, 9.0, 5.0]
```

However, a more pythonic way would be something like

```
for first, middle, last in zip(A[:], A[1:], A[2:]):
    if first < middle > last:
        y_maxtab.append(middle)
print y_maxtab
# [2.5, 9.0, 5.0]
```

Comment: +1 for pointing out and fixing the errors. But the indexing in the `zip()` is a bit inconsistent.

Comment: Since `zip` stops once the shortest iterable is exhausted, I wasn't careful. To me, it makes the most sense as I've edited it, although the way it's written in @Eelco's answer may be preferable to some.

Comment: I agree, this behavior of `zip` is well known and it looks nicer

Comment: Perhaps the downvote is due to not utilizing the power of `numpy`, but it doesn't seem that OP grasps when one should use `numpy.array` over `list`.

Comment: My corrected code works fine and also the more pythonic version, thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that uses numpy directly. Far faster and cleaner than a python loop, and moreover, it does what you intend it to.

```
local_maximum = (A[:-2]<A[1:-1]) & (A[2:]<A[1:-1])
print A[1:-1][local_maximum]
```

Or slightly more verbose, but perhaps more readable:

```
left, mid, right = A[:-2], A[1:-1], A[2:]
local_maximum = (left<mid) & (right<mid)
print mid[local_maximum]
```